# How do i determine the items populating listview?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

im a noob to android and i am populating a listview with an arrayilst and custom adapter.  I want setup my listview onClickListener to execute commands based to the the items populating the listview.  the listview is dynamically populated with items from the arraylist.  I have tried the position and id parameters with no luck.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

How I instantiate listview, arraylist, and adapter

```
    portfoliolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPortfolios);
    users = new ArrayList<PortfolioRecord>();
    portfoliolist.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.simplerow, users));
    portfoliolist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

My Custom Adapter.

```
public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PortfolioRecord> {
    private ArrayList<PortfolioRecord> users;

    public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<PortfolioRecord> users) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, users);
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);
        }

        PortfolioRecord user = users.get(position);         
        if (user != null) {
            TextView portfolioname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.portfolioname);
            TextView currentvalue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.currentvalue);

            if (portfolioname != null) {
                portfolioname.setText(user.portfolioname);
            }

            if(currentvalue != null) {
                currentvalue.setText("Current Value: " + user.currentvalue );
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}

public class PortfolioRecord {
    public String portfolioname;
    public String currentvalue;

    public PortfolioRecord(String portfolioname, String currentvalue) {
        this.portfolioname = portfolioname;
        this.currentvalue = currentvalue;       
    }
}
```

How i add items to arraylist:

```
            user1 = new PortfolioRecord(pn10, denomination10+portfoliovalue10);        
        users.add(user1);
```

I have added Usernull, user1 and user2 to my arraylist. How do i identify these items? I've tried the folowing code with no luck

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View itemClicked, int position,
        long id) {
     TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(parent.getId()){
    case R.id.listViewPortfolios:
        if(portfoliolist.getSelectedItem()==usernull){
            openCustomDialog();
        }else if(portfoliolist.getSelectedItem()==user1){
            whichportfolio=1;               
        }else if(portfoliolist.getSelectedItem()==user2){
            whichportfolio=2;               
        }
     break;}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to implement OnItemSelectedListener.  Just use this within the existing OnItemClick method:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View itemClicked, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     PortfolioRecord user = users.get(position);

        // I'm not certain what this code block does...
        if(user.equals(usernull)){
             openCustomDialog();
        }else if(user.equals(user1)){
            whichportfolio=1;              
        }else if(user.equals(user2)){
            whichportfolio=2;             
        }}
```

Answer (score 1):

supposing your portfolioRecord object has the following: getTypeofUser()

```
portfoliolist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        String typeofUser =users.get(position).getTypeofUser();
                if(typeofUser == user1 ){
                    whichportfolio=1; 
                 }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing to a OnItemSelectedListener and then you could simply fetch the PortfolioRecord with:

```
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Get the user (PortfolioRecord) that was selected
        PortfolioRecord user = users.get(position);

        // I'm not certain what this code block does...
        if(user.equals(usernull)){
             openCustomDialog();
        }else if(user.equals(user1)){
            whichportfolio=1;               
        }else if(user.equals(user2)){
            whichportfolio=2;               
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but im still not having any luck.

Comment: No, errors.  i implemented your code in onCreate and the listview didn't respond.  then i tried implementing it within the OnItemclick method with no result as well.

Comment: You ListView shouldn't have any other listeners aside from the OnItemSelectedListener and your layout `simplerow.xml` cannot have any listeners either. These extra listeners intercept the touch event before it reaches OnItemSelectedListener. Double check with your debugger or a LogCat statement whether you enter `onItemSelected()`.